# Authorize.net getting subscriber's last payment transaction

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am using Authorize.net ARB to process my payments the thing here is that my SilentPost was not working for 1 week because of some fatal errors on my server so therefore all the transactions that were made from Authorize.Net were not recorded in my database.

I just wanted to know if there is a way to get a subscriber's last payment transaction using AuthnetARB.

I know there's this part of the ARB API called `ARBGetSubscriptionStatusRequest` which I can call, the problem with this is it only returns this values:

```
<ARBGetSubscriptionStatusResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/
XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
 <refId>Sample</refId>
 <messages>
 <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
 <message>
 <code>I00001</code>
 <text>Successful</text>
 </message>
 </messages>
 <Status>active</Status>
</ARBGetSubscriptionStatusResponse>
```

As you can see there's no part where it tells me how much the subscriber paid and the payment date. I wanted those information since for me those are the most important.

I also found this link http://www.authorize.net/support/ReportingGuide_XML.pdf, but I think that is not ARB API, because that is Merchant Web Services API. I'm not just sure.

Anyway, I am looking for an Authorize.net ARB API that asks for a subscriber ID since I am storing the subscriber ID in my database, then returns the amount and payment date. Is there a way to do that?

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reporting API is exactly what you'll need to get the information you seek. It can give you the information about the transactions you're missing. You would use `getSettledBatchListRequest` to get the list of the batches in the time period where you had your server issues and then make multiple calls to `getTransactionListRequest` and then ultimately `getTransactionDetailsRequest` to get the transaction information originally sent via silent post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still testing this one in authorize sandbox, it gives me a no result. Would this work on sandbox mode? or it will just give me a result when i'm on live mode?

Comment: This is the result


    <pre><code><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><getSettledBatchListResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"><messages><resultCode>Ok</resultCode><message><code>I00004</code><text>No records found.</text></message></messages></getSettledBatchListResponse>'
 resultCode => 'Ok'
 code => 'I00004'
 text => 'No records found.'
 subscrId => false
}</pre></code>

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't work in sandbox mode but you should contact Authnet to verify that.